# Angular Flickity change elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a flickity which has extra elements added to it as follows:

HTML

```
<div [flickity]="{wrapAround: true}" *ngIf="!isError">
  <div [flickityChild] *ngFor="let item of items" class="slide">
    {{ item.viewValue }}
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
public items: any[] = [];

public ngOnInit() {
  this.loadItems();
}

public loadItems() {
  this.api.loadItems()
    .then(x => this.onItemsLoad(x));
}

private onItemsLoad(items) {
  console.log(items.length);
  this.items = items;
}
```

When it first loads it appears as desired however when `loadItems()` is called a second time it is not displaying/updating correctly.  Below is a screen shot of what is happening:
[image]

There should only be 10 objects in the flickity (shown by the logging), however it contains 20 item indicators and the first 10 items don't work/are invalid.  When I navigate to items 11-20 it displays correctly.

I have also tried updating the original 10 items as follows:

```
public items: any[] = [];

public ngOnInit() {
  this.items.length = 10;
  this.loadItems();
}
..

private onItemsLoad(items) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    this.items[i] = items[i];
  }
}
```

However the same happens.

I am using:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
flickity: 2.1.0
ngx-flickity: 0.0.9
```

Edit: For example see (sorry it does not look nice, but you can see by clicking reload more items are being added):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8eemsv

Comment: Can you please make a [stackblitz](http://www.stackblitz.com) or something to replicate your issue.

Comment: @Zze I have added a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which required modifying the code for ngx-flickity (https://github.com/geex-arts/ngx-flickity). I have made a local copy of the git repository where I have edited the following files:

> src/components/flickity/flickity.directive.ts

Add a remove method anywhere in the class as follows:

```
remove(el: HTMLElement) {
  this.flkty.remove(el);
}
```

> src/components/flickity-child/flickity-child.directive.ts

Make the file implement OnDestroy as follows:

```
import {
  Directive, Optional, Host, ElementRef, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

...

export class  FlickityChildDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (!this.parent) {
      return;
    }

    this.parent.remove(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

*Note: only showing changed lines*